# Errors when moving PostgreSQL databases

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to dump and import a database into a different user on different hosts, both using PostgreSQL 9.4.

I've been following what has been advised in multiple answers here, however I'm still puzzled on one part.

I dump the original database with the following command:

```
pg_dump -d test --clean --no-owner -f test.sql
```

On the target machine, after a clear start (initdb), I do the following:

1. `createuser test`

2. `createdb -O test test`

3. `psql -l` now displays test - test as name and owner

4. Now if I try to import using: `psql -U test -d test -f test.sql` I end up with a huge amount of errors like:

```
ERROR:  relation "public.x" does not exist
ERROR:  index "y" does not exist
ERROR:  sequence "z" does not exist
ERROR:  table "u" does not exist
ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql
ERROR:  must be owner of schema public
ERROR:  schema "public" already exists
```

However, even with all those errors, the import seems to complete and doing a dump on the target machine end up with an identical sql file to the source (except for the two superuser lines at the very end).

Should I be concerned about those errors? Why does it happen and what should I do differently to avoid those errors? Is this the recommended way of moving databases between servers / users?

Comment: Please re-run with `psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 ...` to see the *first* error

Comment: After adding the --if-exists option as per @alexius 's suggestion, this line stops at "must be owner of extension plpgsql"

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behaviour since you made backup with --clean option. In that case sql script is trying to remove database objects before creating them but can't find any.

You may ignore them or create dump without --clean option or with additional --if-exists option (not sure if it will remove all errors).

Comment: thanks, adding the --if-exists seems to have cleared up almost all errors, now stopping at the first one gives: a "must be owner of extension plpgsql" one

Comment: most likely it tries to recreate plpgsql extension, you may ignore this, no big deal. or run under postgres user.

Comment: actually, --clean option is rarely used, it only needed if you want to merge existing data with data from dump, otherwise it's easier to recreate database.

Comment: Yes, I've come to the same conclusion, that dropdb + createdb is a better option then --clean --if-exists

Comment: Yes, it's a bug in PG which is still present: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/E1VuYH7-0008Rz-SV@wrigleys.postgresql.org